# Keeping state of UISwitch in TableViewCell: Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uiswitch, uitableview

I have an issue, I have a tableview setup, users can add and delete new items but also can check them in and out. What I mean by that, is that with every cell that is added there comes a UISwitch in that cell that the user can turn on and off. "on" being checked in and "off" being checked out.

so, with that, I am very new to programming and would like to know how I could save the state(whether it is off or on) of the UISwitch so that every time the user leaves the application the switch stays the same. Thank you for your help.

Current Code:
[current cell code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzQ50.png)

Comment: depends. are the contents of the table view dynamic or static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were new with iOS development,NSUserDefaults is easier to use.Just save data like this:`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] saveObject:data forKey:@""];`And read data like this:`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@""]`

Answer (score 1):

You should use a data persistance to save your configuration (state on and off) and then get them back. There are many options here Core Data (local database), UserDefault, SQLite or even Property Lists. below a helpful [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/beginning-ios-development-data-persistence--mobile-4645) where you can start. Good luck.